# Foreign key is not valid in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have Code First Approach here. I have listed the models below

```
public class BookInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int BookInfoid { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Publisher")]
    public int Publisherid { get; set; }
    public string Edition { get; set; }
    public string Printing { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string CoberPage { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Thikness { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
    public string AmazonLink { get; set; }

    //public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
   // public BookByAuthor BookByAuthor { get; set; }
   // public ICollection<BookByCategory> BookByCategory { get; set; }
    public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }
   public LibraryBook LibraryBook { get; set; }
}

  public class BookStatus
{
    [Key]
    public int BookStatusid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

   public LibraryBook LibraryBook { get; set; }
}


  public class LibraryBook
   {
    [Key]
    public int LibraryBookid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BookInfo")]
    public int BookInfoid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BookStatus")]
    public int BookStatusid { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime ObtainedFrom { get; set; }

    //public ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BookStatus> BooksStatus { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BookInfo> BooksInfo { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext is

```
   public class DBContext:DbContext
   {
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Publisher> Publishers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BookInfo> BooksInfo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BookStatus> BooksStatus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LibraryBook> LibraryBooks { get; set; }
   // public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
```

}

When I try to add a Controller  I am Getting an error as given below. I am using MVC5(Code First Approach)

**Unable to retrieve metadata for Library_management_Syatem.LibraryBook.The Foreignkey Attribute on property 'BookInfoid'on type 'Library_management_Syatem.LibraryBook' is not valid. The Navigation Property 'BookInfoid' was not found on the dependent type 'Library_management_Syatem.LibraryBook'. The name value should be a valid navigation propertye.

Please Help Me**

Answer (score 0):

You've got the "ForeignKey" attribute on the wrong property.  This is how it should be for the publisher (I think it helps to put "virtual" on the complex types):

```
public class BookInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int BookInfoid { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Publisherid { get; set; }
    public string Edition { get; set; }
    public string Printing { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string CoberPage { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePublished { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Thikness { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
    public string AmazonLink { get; set; }

    //public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
   // public BookByAuthor BookByAuthor { get; set; }
   // public ICollection<BookByCategory> BookByCategory { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Publisherid")]       
   public virtual Publisher Publisher { get; set; }
   public LibraryBook LibraryBook { get; set; }
}
```